# Show username in navbar after login

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am struggling to make username show after login in navbar.

When I login with the correct username and password I am just redirected to page. But nothing changes in navbar. Can anyone help me with some tips of what I should do? Feel like I have tried everything and cant see the problem :(

Navbar.ejs:

```
    <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light position-fixed w-100 fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
            </li>
            
            <% if (typeof user !== 'undefined' && user) { %>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <span class="nav-link">Welcome, <%= user.username %></span>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="/logout">Logout</a>
                </li>
              <% } else { %>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="/login">Sign in</a>
                </li>
              <% } %>
              

        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Login.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const fs = require("fs")
const path = require("path")
var passport = require('passport')
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');

passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb) {
  process.nextTick(function() {
    cb(null, { id: user.id, username: user.username });
  });
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, cb) {
  process.nextTick(function() {
    return cb(null, user);
  });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function verify(username, password, cb) {
    let usersArray = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "../data/users.json")));
    let filteredArray = usersArray.filter(x => x.username == username); 
    if (filteredArray.length > 0) {
      let usersData = filteredArray[0];
      if (usersData.password == password) {
        return cb(null, usersData);
      }
    }
    return cb(null, false);
  }));
  
  router.post('/password', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successReturnToOrRedirect: '/memes',
    failureRedirect: '/login'
  }));
  


  router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    if(!req.user) {
      res.render('login', {user: null});
    }
    else {
      res.render('login', {user: req.user});
    }
  });

  router.post('/logout', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.user); // Ensure req.user is defined
    req.logout(function(err) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        res.redirect('/login');
    });
});

  
  module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're checking just for the falsy without explicity checking for the undefined value then you can minimize this process by checking

```
<% if (!user) { %>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/login">Sign in</a>
       </li>        
      <% } else { %>
       <li class="nav-item">
       <span class="nav-link">Welcome, <%= user.username %> 
  </span>
        </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="/logout">Logout</a>
          </li>
          <% } %>
```

{no user might be server error or authentication failed}
now what this will do is it'll check all the false condition and if any false condition meet then you're converting it true so make and don't display it and then in the else block try to access `user.username`

try this and let me know